# Confused about difference between CORS settings in C# and Azure app service

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I created an API in C#. Using the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/security?view=aspnetcore-3.1) I have also added the C# code for enabling CORS. After deploying my app to app service in Azure I notice a section on CORS settings

[image].

Now I'm confused about how these settings work together. Does one setting override the other? Do I need to enable CORS in both C# and the Azure settings? What if they conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use the CORS settings in your app, OR use the CORS settings in Azure. Not both. I set CORS settings in my webAPI and someone changed the CORS settings in Azure and everything broke. Now, I am pretty sure one didn't over-ride the other, but caused catastrophic results. It could have been a bug as it happened years ago, but just know you should only use one or the other exclusively.